# Display content inline with menu

Tags: css, menu

I have used the following code to create a simple right vertical menu

```
#cssmenu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: right;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align:right;  
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul,
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: -1px;
  right: 99%;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu a {
  display: block;
}
/* Custom CSS Styles */
#cssmenu {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  background: #F0EFEA;
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  background: #407a1e url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAARCAMAAAArHTYgAAAAM1BMVEVMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNeSdtTAAAAEHRSTlP2697Pv66biXZkUUAwIRQJC+dRrgAAACJJREFUeF4FwIcNgCAAALCyN/r/tcSPIEqyomq6YVq24/oeBwoAieqEWU4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat-x;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #4b8e23), color-stop(1, #407a1e));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4b8e23, #407a1e);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4b8e23, #407a1e);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4b8e23, #407a1e);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4b8e23, #407a1e);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#4b8e23, #407a1e);
  color: #FFF;
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover > a,
#cssmenu ul li:hover > a {
  color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #327E04;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  width: 150px;
}
#cssmenu a {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
#cssmenu a:link,
#cssmenu a:visited {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu a:hover {
  background: #4b8e23 url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAARCAMAAAArHTYgAAAAM1BMVEVMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNMjiNeSdtTAAAAEHRSTlP2697Pv66biXZkUUAwIRQJC+dRrgAAACJJREFUeF4FwIcNgCAAALCyN/r/tcSPIEqyomq6YVq24/oeBwoAieqEWU4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat-x;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #6ea936), color-stop(1, #4b8e23));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6ea936, #4b8e23);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6ea936, #4b8e23);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6ea936, #4b8e23);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6ea936, #4b8e23);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#6ea936, #4b8e23);
  color: #FFF;
}
#cssmenu a:active {
  color: #ffa500;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > a:after,
#cssmenu .has-sub.hover > a:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #FFF;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub > a:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px 4px 4px 0px;
  border-color: transparent #808080 transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5%;
  margin-top: -4px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8jk2V/1/

However, After adding this menu to all pages, I see that all content of page is coming after the menu.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrWWD.png)

How do I make the content to start from top of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `float`:

```
#cssmenu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  float: right;
}
```